# How do I add content to html body using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, append

when a given array includes a list of employees

```js
let names = [
  { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', DOB: '01Jan1970', role: 'cook' },
  { firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jane', DOB: '11Sep2000', role: 'server' },
];
```

and #ul is already provided,

```html
<ul id="container">
  <li>
    <a class="name">John Doe</a>
    <div class="age">41</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="name">Mary Jane</a>
    <div class="age">20</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to **return a role of an employee when employee's name is clicked**. here is my code

```js
function findRoles(array) {

  const container = document.getElementById('container');

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const li = document.createElement('li'),
      a = document.createElement('a'),
      div = document.createElement('div');
      ul = document.createElement('ul');

    let user = array[i];

    a.innerText = user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
    a.className = 'name';
    a.addEventListener("click", () => printRole(user))


    //div.className = "age";

    li.appendChild(a);
    li.appendChild(div);
    container.appendChild(li);
    
  }
  
}
```

which results this following error :

```
AssertionError: expected '<a class="name"></a>' to equal '<a class="name">John Doe</a>'
```

It appears contents of `<a class="name">` is missing.
been working on this for the past 4 hours and don't seem to figure it out

Comment: Except for the undefined `ul`, your code works as is so I would guess there are some names missing in the list of employees or there is an error somewhere else: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-hoover-w8v6i?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems working in snippet. Just added the printRole method.

```js
function printRole(usr) {
  console.log('Clicked on user: ', `${usr.firstName} ${usr.lastName}`, '; Role is ', usr.role);
}

function findRoles(array) {

  const container = document.getElementById('container');

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const li = document.createElement('li'),
      a = document.createElement('a'),
      div = document.createElement('div');
      ul = document.createElement('ul');

    let user = array[i];

    a.innerText = user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
    a.className = 'name';
    a.addEventListener("click", () => printRole(user))


    //div.className = "age";

    li.appendChild(a);
    li.appendChild(div);
    container.appendChild(li);
    
  }
  
}

let names = [
  { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', DOB: '01Jan1970', role: 'cook' },
  { firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jane', DOB: '11Sep2000', role: 'server' },
];

findRoles(names)
```

```html
<div id="container"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to completely change the logic of your js code.

Was it necessary?

```js
let names = [
  { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', DOB: '01Jan1970', role: 'cook' },
  { firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jane', DOB: '11Sep2000', role: 'server' },
];

let name_mans = document.querySelectorAll('.name');

Array.from(name_mans).forEach(function(name_man, i) {
  name_man.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
  console.log(names[i].role);
   
  });
});
```

```html
<ul id="container">
  <li>
    <a class="name">John Doe</a>
    <div class="age">41</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="name">Mary Jane</a>
    <div class="age">20</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```